# Oil drilling in the Cretaceous possible?

Tags: science-based, time-travel

It's the year 2100, oil reserves are mostly used up. 
In this hard times Evil Corp has invented time travel and it send back engineers and material to drill for oil in the Creaceous.

The question:
Is there oil to be found in the Cretaceous?
If so will it be at the same places as on todays Earth?

**EDIT:**
Evil Corp invented timetravel using a rift in spacetime and it ONLY goes back to the Creaceous. So no other possible destinations in time are reachable.

Comment: Why go back so far? All they need to do is beat everyone else to the already known reserves. Good luck in solving those paradoxes :D

Comment: And then, [Good Guys figure out their evil plot and send their own people to stop Evil Corp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_War).

Comment: ...which in turn is based on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Day_of_Creation  In short: don't mess wit the timelines because others will get the same idea and then you are in for a huge Charlie Foxtrot. :D

Comment: Agreed - go back to 1500 or even 1900 and conduct oil drilling.  However, that is not your question.  I'll try tot take a stab at the geologic answer to 65 million years ago.

Comment: I find the idea of running out of oil laughable. I mean, things have been dying for millions of years replacing our oil reserves, and we've only begun to tap them.

Comment: If they go back and get the oil before it was being used pre-2100 you would find yourself in a sort of grandfather paradox where the oil was used up before people could actually find it and using it... Evil Corp should just go back with all the tech advancements, build themselves an Evil Utopia and live large...

Comment: I think they could make far more money bringing back dinosaurs to sell.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Funny I didn't know about the book. Thanks I will read it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many fossil fuels formed during the [Carboniferous period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous) (which is how it got its name), so there should be plenty of oil by the time the Cretaceous period rolls around.

You might run into time paradoxes, though, if your plan is to drill for oil before it is supposed to be found in the future.